# Reload on submit form Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using a form_for @user to submit a sign up registration. The controller handles the logic usually when the user is saved to reload the page but for some reason, using javascript and ajax will not reload the page when it saves and creates the new user.

I'm assuming I will need to implement this function somehow to reload the page after it saves? I've been messing around with it but I can't figure out anything that still submits the form properly but also reloads the page after.

I currently have the bottom part commented out so the submit button actually works right now but I have no way of it reloading the page. I know there is a function to reload, but I don't know how to put it in the function below so it actually submits the page correctly.

```
// $(".myform").click(function() {
//     $.ajax({
//        type    : 'POST',
//        url     : '/', // like the "action" path on your form element
//        data    : $("myform").serialize(), // serialize your form data
//        success : function(response){
//            // the form was submitted successfully
//            // so now you can reload with javascript
//             location.reload();
//        }
//     });

//     // stop default behavior of submitting the form
//     return false;
// });
```

The form I'm trying to submit is:

```
<%= form_for @user, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <div id="msform">
<!-- multistep form -->
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Part 1</li>
    <li>Part 2</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Part 1</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Name/Email/Password</h3>
    <%= f.text_field :username, :placeholder => "Your Name"%><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email"%>
    <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password" %><br />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Part 2</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your site name</h3>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "What do you want to be called?"%><br />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

to reload the current document with javascript do:

```
location.reload();
```

You could try doing this with AJAX so you can make sure your form was submitted before you try to refresh.

```
$("your_form").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
       type    : 'POST',
       url     : 'some\path', // like the "action" path on your form element
       data    : $("your_form").serialize(), // serialize your form data
       success : function(response){
           // the form was submitted successfully
           // so now you can reload with javascript
           // using location.reload();
       }
    });

    // stop default behavior of submitting the form
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Yup, I have that part, but if if I keep that function in there, it doesn't actually submit the form. I have to comment it out for it to work. I followed the tutorial here: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar

Comment: So commenting out return false; doesn't do what you'd like it to? Isn't the purpose of return false to stop the reloading of the page when the form submits? Also, if there isn't any logic inside the click function what's the purpose of having it?

Comment: I have to comment out the entire submit.click function. Those three lines above entirely. If I comment them out completely, the submit function will work and create a new account but it doesn't reload the page like I want. I'm assuming if I want it to submit and reload, I have to implement that function?

Comment: have you tried putting location.reload() inside the click?

Comment: So just return false; location reload(); or even without the return false? If I do that, nothing submits the form to create the account :/

Comment: No if you put location.reload() after return false then that line of code is never executed because the function already exited. I'll add some code one moment.

Comment: Added the following but it still won't reload. It will create the account just fine but it won't reload the page :/

Comment: how about showing some actual code, that might be helpful

Comment: Added to the top, thanks @Alex for all the help. I was playing around with the Ajax part that you suggested to try and find a way to get it to submit the form and also reload but nothing was still working :/